# Drupal 8 Custom Twig Extension service causes drush abnormal termination

Tags: drupal, twig

I'm adding a custom twig extension service to a Drupal 8 module. My services file looks like this:

```
services:
  analytics.my_twig_extension:
    class: Drupal\analytics\TwigExtension\MyTwigExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

I get this error when running `drush cr`:

```sh
 [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally. Check for an exit()
in your Drupal site.
```

When I remove the tags property in services file, like this:

```
services:
  analytics.my_twig_extension:
    class: Drupal\analytics\TwigExtension\MyTwigExtension
```

then `drush cr` works correctly, but my Twig extension functions are not not running at all.

The MyTwigExtension class:

```php
<?php
namespace Drupal\analytics\TwigExtension;
use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_SimpleFilter;

class MyTwigExtension extends \TwigExtension {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('get_type', array($this, 'getType'))
        ];
    }

    public function getType($var) {
        return gettype($var);
    }
}
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Show us the code for the MyTwigExtension class. Also check the log for any errors.

Comment: @2pha I added the `MyTwigExtension` code to the question. Drush is terminating early for some reason. The site on the client side is completely blank. The error logs aren't showing anything related to this.

Answer (score 2):

Jacob, you're a dummy.
I fixed it by simply using `extends \Twig_Extension` instead of `extends \TwigExtension`. A coworker found the answer. Unfortunately, there was no indication in the logs that this was the problem.